# webpack shows incorrect sourcemaps when using tailwibd directives

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, source-maps

I'm using TailwindCSS 2.1+ in `mode: 'jit'` with SCSS, and currently facing the issue.
Let say I created class `.red`

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Devtools shows it came from `_elements.scss:28` which is correct.
But when I use `@apply`

```
.red {
    @apply text-red-500;
}
```

it shows `%3Cno%20source%3E:1` and so on. Any tailwind style are not being tracked 'properly'.

My **webpack.config.js** (simplified)

```
const config = {
    devtool: isProd ? false : 'eval-cheap-source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(s?)(a|c)ss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: isProd ? {
                                    'autoprefixer': {},
                                    'cssnano': { preset: 'default' },
                                } :
                                    {},
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Options for loaders like `sourceMaps, importLoaders` didn't help.

**postcss.config.js**

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss(),
    ],
};
```

Is there anything I could do to show correct file and line from sourcemaps when using `@apply`?

Comment: It works when using both a normal css rule AND @apply within the same block.

Comment: Fixed in 3.0.24 release - [link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/7588)